# Foreign keys on create table doesn't get created

Tags: mysql

Executing my code didn't cause errors and didn't create the expected keys on this server:

```
create table table1 (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(10) not null default ''   
) engine=innodb;

create table table2 (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    idTable1 int null references table1(id) on delete cascade
) engine=innodb;
```

I've seen some declaring the constraints as:

```
columnName int not null, foreign key (columnName) references table1(id) on delete cascade
```

but I think I've already used the previous syntax before and it worked on a different server. I just can't remember for sure.

Have you seen this before? Am I wrong in assuming my syntax would work as it works on MSSQL? If so, why this doesn't cause an error to be thrown?

**Edit.:**

InnoDB is enabled and set to default with `SET storage_engine=INNODB;` before running the queries to make sure.

Keys added with the second syntax example work. Keys added with alter table work also.

Comment: doesn't create the keys how? you get an error? they don't show up in `show create table table1`?

Comment: The query runs without errors, as stated on my first line, and the key doesn't show up on `show create table table1`.

Comment: then make sure innodb's enabled. mysql can/will silently revert to myisam if innodb's not available. myisam will accept FK stuff, but ignore it otherwise.

Comment: InnoDB is set as DEFAULT on "Support" column of `show engines;`

Comment: that is odd... can you add the FK definition after the fact with an `alter` query? If that works, then something's goofy with your initial syntax. if the alter doesn't work, then something's screwy with your mysql install.

Comment: A FK key added with alter table works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support column level Foreign key constraint addition to the CREATE syntax.
It has to be table level.

> Furthermore, MySQL does not recognize or support “inline REFERENCES
>   specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references
>   are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts
>   REFERENCES clauses only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN
>   KEY specification. For storage engines that do not support foreign
>   keys (such as MyISAM), MySQL Server parses and ignores foreign key
>   specifications.

Further reading: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks. It seems I've wrong assumptions. BTW, do you have any idea or reference to why this doesn't causes MySQL to return an error?

Comment: @rcdmk, don't really have an idea of absence of error/warning msg. MySQL is having habit of silently swallowing many definition syntaxes. Seems like people being facing this since long. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17943